# source of character-level ngrams that include spaces

Tags: data-request, language, english, corpora

I'm looking for a source of character-level ngrams and counts that include spaces. I've found character-level ngram datasets, but they don't include spaces. Ideally, the dataset will include up to 8-grams and be based on a broad swath of English language text.

For example, "the quic" should be one of the 8-grams in the dataset.

Comment: Any reason you want ngrams and not original text? It is probably easier to get a well-understood "broad swath" of text than the same text pre-processed to a model. Generating the ngrams is also pretty easy once you have the source text.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @NeilSlater's comment, you can easily calculate character N-grams with a few lines of code.

In this snippet, I use Python's [Collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) library, which is quite fast for these types of applications:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_char_ngram(text,N):
    data = defaultdict(int) # for speed

    for i in xrange(len(text)-N+1):
        x = text[i:i+N] # actual N-gram
        data[x] += 1    # add 1 to this N-gram key
    return data

print make_char_ngram('ABC the quick brown fox the quick brown fox the quick brown fox XYZ',8)
```

gives you character 8-grams as a dictionary, where the key is the character N-gram, and the value is the count of that case:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'brown fo': 3, 'ck brown': 3, 'n fox th': 2, 'own fox ': 3, ' the qui': 3, ' quick b': 3, 'rown fox': 3, 'uick bro': 3, 'k brown ': 3, ' fox the': 2, 'e quick ': 3, 'fox the ': 2, ' fox XYZ': 1, 'ox the q': 2, 'wn fox X': 1, ' brown f': 3, 'ick brow': 3, 'BC the q': 1, 'the quic': 3, 'quick br': 3, 'ABC the ': 1, 'wn fox t': 2, 'C the qu': 1, 'n fox XY': 1, 'he quick': 3, 'x the qu': 2})
```

([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532044/2327328))

---

In terms of performance, this code went through a 6.2MB [text file](http://norvig.com/big.txt) with 128k lines in 4.5 seconds on my laptop (but not writing the results).

---

If you want to parse massive amounts of text, consider writing these dictionaries to a NoSQL database like MongoDB. In this case, you can parse text in pieces and don't need to run the thing from the start every time. Writing a Python dictionary to MongoDB should be easy (perhaps transform the dict to JSON and then the import is direct).